# tcpdump host filter doesn't work

Tags: tcpdump

I'm using tcpdump on a linux ARM computer (Raspberry Pi). The command `tcpdump host "ip" -v` gives nothing when I go on the website "ip" with my laptop, but if I try `tcpdump port 80 -v` it works properly, I see packets.

Why doesn't the host filter work?

Comment: Most web sites use more than one IP address to serve information to clients, are you sure you are filtering all of it's IPs? How did you obtain them?

Comment: You can check that you're filtering on the correct IP address by doing `tcpdump -n port 80` and looking at the source address.

Comment: How are the Raspberry and the laptop connected? Are they connected via a switch? Is "IP" an ip address or a dns hostname?

Comment: with tcpdump -n port 80 -v i see nothing when i call websites.

Comment: What's the laptop doing here? You mention both a laptop and a Pi but there's no connection between the two. Are proxies involved? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Which interface are you listening on? Is it the correct interface for that IP address?

Answer (score 0):

`tcpdump` can only show packets it sees. And unless you use your raspberry pi as a proxy (or you live in the 90's and use a hub) your raspberry pi will not see any packet that your laptop transmits to anything else than the raspberry pi.